# First icon gets selected everywhere in any page

Tags: windows, windows-error-reporting

So this is the problem in my sister's laptop and I couldn't figure out what's causing it. The laptop behaves as if the Page up button is being pressed continuously even though it isn't pressed. Here are 3 examples to illustrate:

1. When at desktop the first icon gets always selected regardless of wherever I click
   [image]
2. Opening my computer (Folder 6) gets selected wherever I click
   [image]
3. Opening Local disk E, the first folder gets selected even if i click on other folders. Only the first folder opens when i try to open other folders and I couldn't scroll down since the selection runs back to the first folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the keyboard try to connect an external keyboard and disable the device keyboard from device manager for testing purpose... if it is may be u need some hardware changes... hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Go to deice manager

Select keyboard
Right click and uninstall driver
Then restart the pc or laptop
It will re install it automatically during restarting

Answer (score 0):

Hold down and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. Click Task Manager, click the Startup tab, disable all Startup items. Click ok.
Restart or shut down and restart computer. Problem will be gone. Periodically create system restore points for use in case they are needed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go to registry editor by clicking run --> regedit.
In regedit, go to the following registry entry:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

In advanced option select registry name 'Autocheckselect'; select the key and change its value from 0 to 1.

Note: this is tested only for Windows 8. Other versions can have different registry keys.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem myself. Try pressing page up button after booting and it should work fine afterwards. Try it.